Anyone recognise this icon?
[![We have this image supplied to us by a concerned client. Normally we're pretty good at ID'ing these off the bat but this ones proving difficult to ID.][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ix70gSFW.png strong text

It's unclear if this is an app icon of notification icon. If it's a notification icon, then please follow the duplicate question. However, we don't accept random app/notification icon identification anymore because there are million of Android apps and it's unlikely to help anyone else. Sorry.

Might be a custom Bromite icon.
